# Vuforia target asset available in my phone but not in my account

Tags: ios, assets, vuforia, account

I just tested the iOS application Vuforia creator on one meeting room. It works well and I can see that tracking is working. Unfortunately, I cannot see that asset in my account ? Do I need to do something so that I can see it and use it ? I want to test the tracking on another phone for instance.

Thanks !

Charlie

I tried logging on to my account via the web app and the iOS app (on another phone) but it only says "no assets available".
I was expecting my newly created asset to appear in "My assets".

Comment: I should say that I did log on to my account to save as Area target (I can totally see the room in the phone I scanned the room with). It should appear under my account whichever the device I access my account with

Answer (score 1):

If you saved the scan as an Area Target, it should appear in your Assets folder. See the screenshot in Vuforia's guide: https://developer.vuforia.com/library/tools/creator-app#area-targets. If it's not there, try locating it in the app's folder on your device - /Vuforia Creator/.

And you cannot see your assets on another device because your scanned spaces and all your other assets are only stored locally. You need to transfer the database files to the other device and load them from the Creator App to see them. It's also described in the guide I linked.

Hope it helps,